# TestNG Selenium ChromeDriver : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng

by wanting to perform a first execution of my framework, i launch a simple testcase with Selenium - testNG on intellij IDEA and, i have an error of which I do not know the real origin.

This is my POM.xml dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.selenium.framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>framework-selenium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

my simple test java class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

public class firstAutomateTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeTest(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Drivers/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).submit();

        String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        assertTrue(pageTitle.contains("Selenium"));

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTest(){
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

and i have this error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22 (398b0743353ff36fb1b82468f63a3a93b4e2e89e-refs/branch-heads/4240@{#378}) on port 15650
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.



java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet(java.util.Comparator)'

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.lambda$validate$3(NewSessionPayload.java:191)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:441)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.validate(NewSessionPayload.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.<init>(NewSessionPayload.java:152)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:105)
    at firstAutomateTest.beforeTest(firstAutomateTest.java:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:61)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:366)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:320)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:701)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:527)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Please has anyone ever had this error and know what it is?

Thanks

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` indicates following: the class if found but not the method inside the class. Thus it very likely is a __version-mismatch__ (compatibility of you maven-dependencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Selenium latest stable version 3.141.59 instead of the alpha version.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG 7.3.0 is using guice: 4.2.2 & guave:25.1-andorid . It creates problem for the Selenium Alpha version as its using  guava.30.0.-jre .

**Error :**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector
> com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet(java.util.Comparator)'

For above error add below dependency in POM.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>30.0-jre</version>
    </dependency
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in maven dependencies this one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>25.0-jre</version>
 </dependency
```

Here you have a list of guava compatible versions:

- Selenium v2.49.0 : Bump guava to version 19
- Selenium v3.1.0 : Requires an update to the latest guava version 21.0
- Selenium v3.5.0 : Bump guava to version 22.
- Selenium v3.5.1 : Bump guava to version 23.
- Selenium v3.12.0 : guava-23.6-jre
- Selenium v3.13.0 : guava-25.0-jre
- Selenium v3.14.0 : guava-25.0-jre
- Selenium v3.141.0 : guava-25.0-jre
- Selenium v3.141.5 : guava-25.0-jre
- Selenium v3.141.59 : guava-25.0-jre